# java 11 HttpClient leads to endless SSL loop

Tags: java, multithreading, http, http2, java-11

I am using the *new* `java.net.http.HttpClient` with the `sendAsync` method.
The `HttpClient` is inside a Singelton and is created **once** like so:
`HttpClient.newBuilder().build()` so really nothing special.

Those requests can be `POST` or `GET` but I don't know which causes the trouble.

There are just a few requests a day but from time to time one thread uses 100% of a cpu core. And not imminently but after some time when the request has finished.

So I did a thread dump when there were even 2 of those endless loops occurring, the following 2 threads stood out:

```
"HttpClient-4-Worker-5" #144 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=511298.10ms elapsed=520.71s tid=0x00007f684403e800 nid=0x2d6b runnable  [0x00007f68ac162000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.processData(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:771)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer$WriterDownstreamPusher.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:645)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:147)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:198)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:271)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:224)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.triggerWrite(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:722)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:1024)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doClosure(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:1094)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:500)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:389)
        - locked <0x00000000fba68950> (a java.lang.Object)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:263)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:175)
        - locked <0x00000000fbbca3e8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:147)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:198)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.2/Thread.java:834)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000000fc1ff920> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)





"HttpClient-4-Worker-2" #82 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=4266156.67ms elapsed=4311.42s tid=0x00007f6844007000 nid=0x29ee runnable  [0x00007f686fffd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.processData(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:771)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer$WriterDownstreamPusher.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:645)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:147)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:198)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:271)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:224)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.triggerWrite(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:722)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:1024)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doClosure(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:1094)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:500)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:389)
        - locked <0x00000000f97668d0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SSLFlowDelegate.java:263)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:175)
        - locked <0x00000000f97668f0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:147)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.2/SequentialScheduler.java:198)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.2/Thread.java:834)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000000f9894cc0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Same observation but on another container where only one thread was affected.

```
"HttpClient-3-Worker-2" #120 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1100568.51ms elapsed=1113.79s tid=0x00007eff3003b800 nid=0x479 runnable  [0x00007eff83bf8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(java.base@11.0.1/SSLEngineImpl.java:136)
        - eliminated <0x00000000f9796e08> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(java.base@11.0.1/SSLEngineImpl.java:116)
        - locked <0x00000000f9796e08> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(java.base@11.0.1/SSLEngine.java:519)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.wrapBuffers(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:821)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.processData(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:736)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer$WriterDownstreamPusher.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:645)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:147)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:198)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:271)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:224)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.triggerWrite(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:722)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:1024)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doClosure(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:1094)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:500)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:389)
        - locked <0x00000000f9797010> (a java.lang.Object)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SSLFlowDelegate.java:263)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:175)
        - locked <0x00000000f9797030> (a java.lang.Object)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:147)
        at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(java.net.http@11.0.1/SequentialScheduler.java:198)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.1/Thread.java:834)
```

Some example code I am using

```
httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                                .thenApply(logResponse());
```

Java Version

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The problem also occurs when preferring HTTP 2

**Updates**

Am I using the `HttpClient` in a wrong way?
Could this be a Server Problem?
Is it maybe this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207009?

- Client connects to a cloudflare service
- When the issue occurs there are is no open connection to cloudflare via netstat visible
- I can pin the problem to http2 + tlsv1.3 (using the nginx docker image: `nginx:1.15-alpine` with tls1.3 enabled of course)

**Bug appears to be fixed now according to** https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241054

Comment: I can reproduce this on Mac on JDK 13 with just a blocking HttpClient::send followed by a Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE). Changing TLS did nothing.

Comment: This issue is fixed in JDK 13 b04; I was using an earlier build.

Comment: @kantianethics any clue what exactly causes this issue?

Comment: see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217094

Comment: In JDK 11.0.10 this bug is now in httpserver, fix with jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLSv1.3 helps when server thread is stucked at doClosure() after each new client's request before previous request was finished

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @jspcal said before disable TLS 1.3.

**tl;dr**: disable tlsv1.3 via extending/overwriting

`<java_home>/conf/security/java.security` the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property

Since my application is running in a docker container I changed the base image to disable tls1.3

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre
...

RUN sed -i "/jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=/ s/=.*/=TLSv1.3, SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40, 3DES_EDE_CBC/" $(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")/conf/security/java.security
```

As far as I know there is no way of setting this (security) property via a system property! See also `sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints#PROPERTY_TLS_DISABLED_ALGS` which actually ready the property.

**Update**: Bug is still present in 11.0.2

Comment: I see the same problem also with OpenJDK 11.0.6

Answer (score 9):

Try disabling `TLSv1.3` or `SSLv3` to see if that helps.

Set the system property on the command line: `-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLSv1.3`

Or define the property in `<java_home>/conf/security/java.security`

If you think it's an implementation bug, you may want to open an issue.

Comment: Thought about TLS 1.3 issues too ... maybe its this bug here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207009 - not sure if it is fixed in my version

Comment: Interesting link. Thanks.

Comment: Disabling TLS 1.3 did not help :/

Comment: Oh interesting Zarathustra.

Comment: Just found out that even with `-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLSv1.3` the client still uses TLS v1.3

Comment: Disabling TLS 1.3 doesn't work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298459/java-11-httpclient-leads-to-endless-ssl-loop-even-with-disabled-tlsv-1-3

Comment: the parameter -Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLSv1.3 does not work

Answer (score 9):

I run into the same issue and found the
[bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241054)

It is awaiting JDK 11.0.8 release.

Answer (score 4):

The bug was fixed for the 11.0.10 Java version.

Comment: I think in this instance it would be great if you could provide a link to the issue in the appropriate bug tracker